# What do my mean and standard deviation tell me?

Tags: mean, panel-data, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, longitudinal-data-analysis

I have American State level unemployment rates in 3 waves of longitudinal data. When I describe unemployment rates for my descriptive table I get the following:

```
                    Wave 1     Wave 2     Wave 3
                    9% (2)       9%(2)     18%(3)
```

Where the % is local area unemployment in the States of the mothers I will analyze and the standard deviation is in the brackets. When I run my regressions on State unemployment and health I see a significant impact of local area unemployment on my outcome variable, but I am surprised by this because in the descriptive statistics above it looks like unemployment in wave 1 and wave 2 doesn't change across these two waves. Could this be because when I run my regression I have controls that I don't include in my descriptive statistics? Or is it that this is a sample aggregate across all States and that declines in unemployment in some States are cancelling out increases in others at the aggregate level to give the illusion of stasis? Is this normal or will it look weird if I report effects of increases of unemployment on health between waves 1 and 2 in light of these descriptive statistics?

Happy to provide any further detail,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your sample size? This could be a case of practical insignificance. Also, since this is time series data, you have to be careful with the tests. Regression may be inappropriate here (depending on how you did it), since data is time-dependent. Can you show us the code of your model and results?

Comment: The sample size is 400 mothers measured at two waves. I use linear probability models in fixed effects models for binary outcomes (for ease of interpretation, results hold, albeit with a smaller sample for logits). All is done in Stata as follows: xtreg mothers_health local_unemployment parity i.state i.year i.education age fe robust I get a resull of  -.01086724* for the coefficient of interest.